# TC can't build unit test project. No System.Runtime dll

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, teamcity

I am trying to build .sln file in build step of teamcity

[image]

But I got a mistake with test project (part of solution)

```
error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

How can I fix it ?  Unit test project doesn't have app.config where I can write something like

```
  <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </assemblies>
```

Project target framework 4.6.1 . I guess the solution can be to have a folder on TC server like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1` with `System.Runtime.dll`, but I am not sure. On TC server I have folders up to 4.5.2, locally up to 4.6.2, but in 4.6.1 I see no dll - only in 4.6

**Update**

The solution was to install development pack X version and specify target platform parameter for X framework

Comment: What is your development environment? Visual Studio 2015? Compare the MSBuild diagnostics logging on your development machine and the TC agent machine, and you should get some hints.

Comment: What happens when you add a reference to System.Runtime to your project files (i.e. *.csproj, etc..) ?